# Push Android APK update to Google Play Store by command line

Tags: gratis, android, command-line, play-store

I often release Android app updates, and uploading the APK manually to Google Play Store takes a considerable time.

Is there any way to push (update) an APK to Google Play Store via command line?
I would integrate it in my build script.

Requirements:

- Free, ideally open source.
- As it will probably rely on web UI scraping, it doesn't expect 100% reliability.
- Works for beta APKs too.

Comment: See this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829495/how-to-upload-an-android-app-to-the-app-store-via-command-line#comment33038924_21829495) on StackOverflow, that guy has huge knowledge in Android, if he is saying that means such functionality is not present right now.

Comment: @Kedarnath: He said "Nothing that is documented and supported"... hinting that something hacky exists. I am not looking for something documented, even less for something supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API should do it as long as you are not publishing a new app, but the new version of existing app. I've not used it yet, though.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

And if you use Jenkins, there is Jenkins plug-in for this purpose:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin